# Change Loader source and update view

Tags: qt, qml

I have an application in which i am loading some resources inside a main file with a Loader object:

main.qml:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    property string pageSource: pageLoader.source
    ...
    Loader {
        id: pageLoader
        source: "page1.qml"
    }
}
```

In page1.qml i have a layout that wraps some buttons and text fields. Loading this page in `pageLoader` works fine. As you can see i have a  `foo` Button that should switch the source of the Loader to page2.qml, but for some reason it's not working.

page1.qml:

```
Item {
    ColumnLayout {
        TexField {...}
        TexField {...}
        Button {
            id: foo
            onClicked: {
                pageSource = "page2.qml"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By checking some console logs i was able to know that i am actually changing the source of the loader, but the view is not updating as expected and all controls from page1.qml is not replaced by page2.qml. This second page has a `ListView`. Toggling active property of Loader doesn't work either. Can anyone please shed a light?

Comment: Did you try to load pages in main.qml? I've tested the same example and it works well. Probably you have some layout problems. I see you didn't define a size for the loaded page. Try to remove the root `Items` since is's unnecessary.

Comment: That was exactly my mistake. I have entered a comment before and a user answered, but idk why both were deleted. I'm very new to qml. I'll be preparing some elaborated answer to this question and some others i made to help people with the same issue.